# Spring-MVC + RESTeasy form bean validation (JSR 303) with i18n messages

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, resteasy, bean-validation

I have a classic spring-mvc  web application using hibernate form bean validation, that uses i18n bundle files to return error message in the JSP.  (Spring-MVC 4.0.7, Hibernate-validator 5.1.3). Below the corresponding Spring configuration part:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

This works  fine ; my form bean contains annotations like @Length @NotNull @NotEmpty, @Pattern etc…, And the  form JSP returned includes the constraints violation message in the I18N client language . 
For i.e in formBean like :

```
public class MyFormBean {
    @NotEmpty @FormParam("name")
    private String name;    

    @FormParam("type")
    @Length(min=1, max=1) @NotNull
    private String type = "T";

    @NotNull @Pattern(regexp="^[1-9][0-9]*$")
    @FormParam("goal")
    private String goal;
}
```

The messages'keys in my i18n ResourceBundle properties files are like:

```
NotEmpty.myPostFormName.name = the name must be filled  
Pattern.myPostFormName.goal = the goal must be numeric positive.
```

Thereafter, using this tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/articles/resteasy-spring I added a RESTeasy controller part (Cf.  Spring MVC Integration (https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.2.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Spring_Integration.html); (with the dependencies jar: resteasy-spring 3.0.11.Final, and resteasy-validator-provider-11)

But When I do a @Post I cannot customize (and i18n) the message returned. For i.e.:

```
@POST
public Response create (@Context UriInfo uri, @Valid @Form MyFormBean pMyformB) { }
```

I obtain a response body like:

```
<violationReport>
   <parameterViolations>
      <constraintType>PARAMETER</constraintType>
      <path>create.arg1.type</path>
      <message>cannot be null</message>
      <value/>
   </parameterViolations>
   <parameterViolations>
      <constraintType>PARAMETER</constraintType>
      <path>create.arg1.goal</path>
      <message>cannot be null </message>
      <value/>
   </parameterViolations>
 </violationReport>
```

Then I cannot customize the "message" part.

**So how can I use the same (i18n) messageResources files for both: spring-MVC classic post JSP and RESTeasy @POST violation report?**

**[EDIT]** Second question: **is it possible to have a full RESTeasy / SPringMVC integration with the Bean Validation?**
I mean: following the tutorial of the web site (link above) 
If I add @Valid on the POST html request:

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
 public ModelAndView saveContactForm(@Valid @Form Contact contact) throws URISyntaxException {
    service.save(contact);
    return viewAll();
 }
```

The Validation Error is intercepted before and REsteasy return a response (xml by default) so I cannot use the SpringMVC ModelAndView to return the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to switch to `ValidationMessages.properties` as message source. This is the default for Bean Validation and also what the RESTeasy uses. To switch to `ValidationMessages.properties` for Spring MVC it should be enough to adjust the `basename` property of your `messageSource§ bean.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Hardy. Effectively if I change my Spring config by this line:  
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">  
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:ValidationMessages" />   
It works (even if I cannot found any way to customize this path/name or to customize the violationReport ("path" element). The second problem is that the default Locale is used and I cannot intercept the locale chosen by the client.
I also add in my post another question about \@Valid and springMVC-RESTeasy full integration